# API to Json and CSV Schema/Model

Tags: python, json, api, csv, endpoint

I'm currently interviewing for a job position, and I have received a case statement that got me very confused.

So I'm posting this here to see if you folks have a more clear understanding than mine.
They give me a CSV and they ask me to expose this CSV data through an API, what is confusing is the following statement:

> "Your final product should contain a connection to a database where
> the data is stored in a logical schema / model. Add an API endpoint
> from which this dataset can be retrieved in json format. In addition,
> show that the data is stored in a SQL and a NoSQL schema / model. Add
> an extra API endpoint so that we can receive the data from both
> schemas in json format and in csv format. In addition dockerize your
> application. "

What do you understand by the above?
They want the API to send the data as FILES? or it has only to do with the logical modelling of the data?
Would appreciate some comments and what you guys understand from the quotation.
Thanks!

Comment: Which part of the statement is confusing you specifically? There are a few requirements in there. You are focusing on this, I think: `They want the API the send the data as FILES?`...well, from what I ready it sounds like the API should have 2 endpoints: one which returns the data in JSON format, and one which returns it in CSV format.

Comment: The whole statement is kind of confusing to me. I get the part of having two endpoints, but I'm not clear with what it means to have an endpoint that returns data in CSV format? Do I have to create a .csv file? Or it has nothing to do with creating files? I have never seen an API giving .csv format back, so maybe that's why I'm so confused...

Comment: You're just sending a http response. Csv is a data format, and a pretty simple one at that. Add some appropriate response headers and a browser (and maybe other clients, if programmed to do so) will save the response into a .csv file locally. Ultimately though, your API just outputs some text.  Whether that's saved as a file, or shown in a window, or whatever else, is largely down to the client which receives that text. As I mentioned, you can set headers which might encourage certain behaviour, but mainly your API's job is simply to return the data, in whatever format

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now. Send it as a response and I can accept it.